# Not able to access minikube IP address with NodePort

Tags: docker, kubernetes, cloud, devops, minikube

I'm encountering an issue with accessing services deployed in my Minikube cluster from my local machine. I've deployed a Django application inside Minikube and exposed it using a NodePort service. However, when I try to access the service from my local machine using the Minikube IP address and NodePort, I cannot establish a connection.

I've checked the Minikube IP address, ensured network connectivity, and verified that the service runs correctly within the cluster. I've also restarted Minikube, but the issue persists.

Could anyone guide troubleshooting steps or potential solutions to resolve this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Here's what I tried [`kubectl get all`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ampXX.png)
Deployment YAML file [`deployment.yml`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6FxZu.png)
Service YAML file [`service.yml`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vCxI.png)
Minikube SSH - Ping and curl requests work inside SSH [`minikube ssh`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkKDd.png)
However, pinging outside Minikube fails [outside minikube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuAMo.png)

Github - https://github.com/sohitdeveloper/minikube-python-app

I need help, please assist. Thank you.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)  Can you [edit] the question to include the reproduction artifacts directly in the question and in plain text?

Answer (score 0):

Try `minikube service python-django-app-service --url`. This command will give you the exact address and port you've exposed. If this doesn't work, try `kubectl port-forward svc/python-django-app-service 8090:80` where `8090` is the port you need to connect like so `localhost:8090` and see what happens. If the latter doesn't work, 99% of the time, something is wrong with how the port on the application side is exposed. Is this port really in a listening state? Try to run the same container in Docker and expose the port.

Comment: I have tried this way minikube service python-django-app-service --url
earlier and this was working fine...But why it's not working in the minikube standard way...I want to access directly via 
minikube ip and the NodePort.

is it possible ?

Comment: This command is only for printing, so you must be able to access the IP:port without running that command.

Comment: this one is printing http://127.0.0.1:51765
but I don't want to access the application in this way...I want to access it via minikubeIp and NodePort

Comment: You can check my entire code ~
https://github.com/sohitdeveloper/minikube-python-app